# Adjust (MMP) and Google Sheets Integration

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to know if there is any way to create an automation that will bring data from Adjust and put it into a spreadsheet from Google Sheets.
I believe it may have a possibility via Script but I don't know how to do it.

Many thanks!

I've looked for solutions over internet and I don't want a 3rd-partner connector to do so.

Comment: I believe it's fair to say that is what apps script is for.- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) It can also be done with Java and Python

Comment: Adjust has an API and this can export data to Google Sheets in several ways. AS as script-based options, there appears to be a "built-in export feature to export data in CSV format and then importing the CSV file into Google Sheets manually" Perhaps this approach would enable you to identify your process flow and you can focus on developing apps that target specific processes.